unable to read event listener defined in backtick of button
I am trying to assign an onClick function to remove button but the function is not being read here, i tried the same syntax in html file and it worked but it doesnt work in a .jsx file.
function addTodoToDom(addedTodo) {
  const parent = document.getElementById('todo-container');
  const child = document.createElement('div');
  const childTitle = document.createElement('div');
  childTitle.innerHTML = addedTodo[0].title;
  const childDescription = document.createElement('div');
  childDescription.innerHTML = addedTodo[0].description;
  const removeButton = document.createElement('button');
  removeButton.innerHTML = 'Remove Todo';
  removeButton.setAttribute('onClick',`removeTodo(${addedTodo[0].id})`);
  child.appendChild(childTitle);
  child.appendChild(childDescription);
  child.setAttribute("id", addedTodo[0].id);
  child.appendChild(removeButton);
  parent.appendChild(child);
  
}

function removeTodo(todoId){
      todoState = todoState.filter((todo) => todo.id != todoId);
      updateState(todoState);
}

error in console
I tried to remove the backtick and just write the function name, but then it does not work as I want it to. However the function is begin read in that case

if that code is in a javascript module, then removeTodo is not a global function therefore not callable from a onclick= attribute - have you considered using addEventListener instead? or you could window.removeTodo = removeTodo if you really want to keep polluting the global object :p
